# Regex model validation (digits or empty string)

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to match a number of 1-5 digits or empty string for model validation:
Model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{0,5}", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
public string ServiceNumber { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceNumber)
```

This doesn't let me leave out the input empty.

Comment: So you're getting an error on empty string?

Comment: @Jack, yes Html.ValidationSummary displays the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `\d{1,5}|^$`? The `^$` is an empty string because `^` is the start of the string and `$` is the end of the string in regex so `^$` means start and end string with nothing inside.  The `|` means OR, either match 1-5 digits OR empty string.

Comment: `\d{0,5}` can never fail to match.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `@"(\d{1,5})?"` ?